# Is it compulsory to reinstall the app to get updated data from SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

My app renders some data from SQLite database. If I update something in the database and build the app from android studio it doesn't show any changes. But, I uninstall and again build the app then only it shows the changes.

I don't want it because I then when I publish app and give some updates including update in data of database **users can't see any changes?, they should reinstall to see changes**?

I guess that because I should do the same when building the app from android studio to my phone.

Is there any solution to bring changes from SQLite without reinstalling? Maybe in manifest?

I tried `android:allowBackup="true"` and `android:allowBackup="false"` one by one but It didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create an app with Sql database, it does not change everytime you run the app as a part of efficiency. But to change its data you can do any one of the following things:

1. Reinstall the app.
2. Clear the data of app from device settings
3. Change the version of the database in your code

I find 3rd one as much easiest one.

Hope it helps! Happy Coding.

Comment: yeah, it helps. thank you so so so so so much.
Happy Coding :)